# XeLaTeX Bad/Inconsistent Kerning

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, libertine, kerning

I'm running xubuntu 12.04.3 LTS with tex-full 2013 package. The kerning is terrible. For example, I have fonts-linuxlibertine 5.3.0 installed, latest and greatest; when I compile using XeLaTeX, both libertine and biolinum fontfaces get poor/inconsistent kerning.
[image: Linux Biolinum O]

Fig 1. Linux Biolinum O. See kerning differences in "Brief".

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Biolinum O} 
\title{Jones Construction Creative Brief}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Edit: Tested on other pdf readers
[image: Adobe Reader]

Fig 2. Seen on Adobe Reader Win7.

It looks significantly better on Adobe Reader though that Br pair still looks questionable. I'm not sure if I have a real problem at this point, everything looks much more acceptable. I might just need to manually kern some things.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try with another PDF viewer?

Comment: Nope, installing.

Comment: Here's what I can tell. It's not a problem with XeLaTeX as using LuaLaTeX produces the same result. Next, I am not an expert with typography but the only problem I notice is with the "r"s -- they are all messed up with too much space on the left side. Since these two fonts were made by the same person this means that most likely there's a problem with the fonts, maybe something called their "font tables"? (I see that phrase thrown around a lot). So yes, using something like microtype you can fix the kerning for that one letter. I can attempt a fix if you need it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a font problem not solvable on the TeX side